# NativeScript Interconnected apps

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I'm looking into if its possible to make NativeScript interconnected apps. So basically I have a main app.
The main app would contain API callers, Login, and security.

The other apps would mainly handle the interface, but when needing data they would use the main apps API.

Is this possible using NativeScript?

The other alternative would be having a main app with everything in, and then the others would basically just be "links", but i actually don't like that idea very much.

Thanks in advance.

-- On that note and before you ask why I would ever do this kinda of thing, I can tell you the system works with some kinda security intensive stuff, and most people feel bad when these things are mixed together. So it's actually more of a UX - human feel thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for iOS the methods for app to app communication are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html).

url schemes are often used to transfer control to another app.

for Android, they tend to use intents which are described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html).

there is not really a cross platform way of handling this, however some have tried. Maybe [nativescript-open-app](http://plugins.nativescript.org/plugin/nativescript-open-app) will work for you.

Comment: Sorry it took me a bit of time to research your answer, and thanks for guiding me in the right direction.